# Blank Screen on Mint 15 LiveCD

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, live-usb

I own a Lenovo Yoga 11s (i5 processor, Intel integrated graphics) and I'm trying to install Linux Mint on to it. However, after I boot from the live cd, the screen goes blank and stops responding. I've looked into the problem online, and I see that it might be an issue with the graphics card.
However, any fix I find online has been useless in alleviating the problem.

What can I do next to solve this problem?

Comment: What fixes have you tried so we don't suggest the same? Did you try adding `nomodeset` to the kernel options line in GRUB?

Answer (score 1):

[Live CD wont boot - black screen (of death)](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=189&t=112524)

At the bootloader, press Tab to edit an entry. Provide "`radeon.modeset=0`" (without quotes) at the end but before the dashes.

Don't ask me why...

Comment: The OP says they are using an Intel graphics card, so the correct KMS switch to disable modesetting is `i915.modeset=0`.

Comment: This comment is correct, and also works for the Lenovo Yoga 13.

Answer (score 0):

A friend in university had a similar issue after installing Mint on his laptop (dual-boot). When booting into Mint the screen would appear blank. The solution was actually that the brightness was being reset to 0 (for whatever reason - I don't know). I know it sounds weird, but it may be that simple. I'd guess that you'd have tried that already, but in the event you haven't...